# LocalDumps registry key stopped working (Windows Error Reporting)

Tags: windows, crash-dumps, windows-error-reporting

I set up the registry key, HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps [as described on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181.aspx).

I have a test program - a console program, compiled with Visual C++, that tries to dereference a NULL pointer before printing a message and exiting.  The test program used to exit and dump a core file, but now it just exits.  I get no core.

I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, SP1 on physical hardware.

I don't know what changed.  What could have changed that prevents WER from dumping cores now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows does not produce full crash dumps even though registry is set correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457570/windows-does-not-produce-full-crash-dumps-even-though-registry-is-set-correctly). The duplicate has a more complete answer. Other than that, it looks like I answered both questions from the same local Wiki I have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following may go wrong:

### Permissions of the folder to write to

Looking at the permissions of the folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER` it has

- Read & execute
- List folder contents
- Read

Creating a subfolder `LocalDumps` will inherit the permissions.

So you should either modify the permissions of that folder or use a different folder with write permissions.

### Permissions of the Registry key

Windows might not be able to read the Registry settings if the permissions do not allow it. E.g. the following (really silly) permissions will prevent a LocalDump as well:

[image: LocalDumps permissions]

### 32 vs. 64 bit

Windows Error Reporting is executed by Windows and only uses the registry key with the bitness of the OS. You said you set up both. If that's true, it`s fine. If you only set up the 32 bit Registry key, it won't work.

### AeDebug

If you have a setting for AeDebug `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug`, those are executed before WER.

Note that this entry may exist in 32 bit (WOW6432Node) and 64 bit.

Usually that should result in starting a debugger, but who knows ... it might do nothing and just exit.

### LocalDumps is disabled

Make sure that there is no DWORD `Disabled` with a value of `1` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps`

### Use of REG_SZ instead of REG_EXPAND_SZ

I have seen people using a REG_SZ for `DumpFolder` in combination with `%APPDATA%`. Only REG_EXPAND_SZ will expand environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added a key on the *LocalDumps* node like "LocalDumps\MyApplication.exe".  Then, update the values that are explained in that link.  At the time of a crash, WER looks for a key with the matching application name to decide how to handle the dump.

Comment: It should also work if the entry is created without "MyApplication.exe", but then it applies for all executables.