# VB & C++ application crashing without any clue

Tags: crash, crash-reports, event-log, crash-dumps, windows-error-reporting

Apologies, this may not be a good question.

I have a VB based UI application running, supported by C++ modules through COM.

a month before it started to close randomly without any clue. I initially analyzed in perspective of a application crash and expected to see Dumps and Application/System event log entries. I have prior experience in application crash debugging. tried registry configurations (Like, CorporarteWerServer for application hang, LocalDumps and all that).

But no luck.

End user says they don't see any popup like "This application is not responding with options close/wait". The application just closes down without any prompts.

We have logging enabled where we intentionally close the application using exit(). So it is not closing formally.

User does not have testing environment where we can install debugging tools and monitor.

I have verified for insufficient memory and antivirus software and they are fine.

**So, Is there any cases where an application can just simply close/crash without any prompts, logs, dumps ?**

**Please suggest if I am missing something. Also, is there any built-in windows tools to monitor ?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LocalDumps registry key stopped working (Windows Error Reporting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535676/localdumps-registry-key-stopped-working-windows-error-reporting)

Comment: You can create a USB stick containing WinDbg. No need to install. It can run portable. Also, turning on Application Verifier can help finding the bug.